# Number of ways people can sit on k tables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, stirling-numbers

We have 6 people which we have to seat at the 2 tables . Each table has 3 chairs to sit on.

How many ways can we seat the people when we do not distinquish the order of tables? If each person has the same person by right and left hand , its the same way.

How could we calculate this using Stirling number of the first kind.

```
s(n, 1) = (n − 1)!, ∀n ≥ 1,
s(n, k) = 0, ∀k > n,
s(n + 1, k) = s(n, k − 1) + n · s(n, k), ∀k, n ∈ N, 1 ≤ k ≤ n.
```

Should be forulas , but how to modify it to reach the right answer?

Comment: As it stands it is difficult for me to clearly comprehend your question. I take it there are two tables, presumably round otherwise people aren't guaranteed to have a person on their left/right. 

Is it that we don't distinguish the different seating arrangements for a table or merely that we don't distinguish between the two tables?

The last sentence "Should be for[m]ulas, but how to modify it to reach the right answer" might need some editing to be parsable.

Comment: The (unsigned) Stirling number ${6\brack 2}$ of the first kind is the number of permutations of $[6]=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with exactly $2$ cycles, but it counts *all* permutations of $[6]$ with exactly $2$ cycles, not just the ones with a pair of $3$-cycles. You want the number of permutations of $[6]$ that consist not just of $2$ cycles, but specifically of a pair of $3$-cycles. There is a formula for the number of permutations of $[n]$ with a given set of cycle sizes; [this webpage](http://blog.plover.com/math/fixpoints.html) and ...

Comment: ... [this PDF](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~momar/PermutationCycleType.pdf) give you a very brief introduction. That formula gives the result $\frac{6!}{3^2\cdot 2!}=40$, but this problem is small enough that it’s at least as easy just to analyze it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Take an individual, who has $5$ candidates for the left-hand position and then $4$ candidates for the right-hand position.  That then leaves three individuals for the other table: take one of those, who has $2$ candidates for the left-hand position and then $1$ candidate for the right-hand position

So there are $5\times 4 \times 2 \times 1=40$ possibilities

This is easily extended to $n$ indistinguishable round tables with $k$ people on each table giving a total of $\dfrac{(nk)!}{n!\,k^n}$ possibilities.  So in this example you have  $\dfrac{6!}{2! \times 3^2}=\dfrac{720}{2 \times 9}=40$

I do not see a connection with Stirling numbers of the first kind